# From iPhone Project to iPad Project using Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to be able to change my iPhone project into an iPad project. This is how I did it:
I changed the Active Executable stuff to iPad and went in to the info and changed the Targeted Device family to iPad. Then I went into Interface Builder and went File > Create iPad Version Using Autosizing Masks. Then I named the new xib that was created exactly the same as the xib it was based of (The iPhone xib). Then I replaced the iPhone xib with the iPad xib. This works fine and launches as an iPad app when I've created a completely new project (Yes I did add some stuff in interface builder to make sure it wasn't that which was make it not working.) But when I do this with the project I want to do it with the app launches in the iPad but as an iPhone app.

The project I want to change from iPhone to iPad is here:
http://icodeblog.com/wp-content/uplo...iCodeOauth.zip

Hope this makes sense guys!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also change/add the iPad window in the info.plist?
You might also need to delete the app from the sim or device, and clean before you build.

Answer (score 5):

take a look at this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's blog: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Perfectly explained.